# Synchronized Connection on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a synchronized database connection for my project and I'm wondering does it cause trouble? Let me explain, how i use this. When the application starts life it connects to the database and it is using one connection until application dies. I prefered this because I need to export database to other documents for db queries. This is my code:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

function connectToDB() {
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try {

        client.connect();
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`\x1b[32m[DONE]\x1b[0m db connection established.`)
        }, 200);
        return client.db('serverDatabase')


    } catch (error) {
        console.error('error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

module.exports = connectToDB();
```

Comment: I don't think we're in a position to answer this question. You mention very briefly why you _prefer_ this approach but there's no way for us to know about your use case to opine on whether or not it is appropriate for such a configuration. Moreover even if we did then the question would invite opinion-based responses. If you can narrow the scope of the concern expressed in the question then it may be appropriate for this site, otherwise if the setup is working for you then I think you should carry on with using it.

Comment: I can't give an exact number but there're about 40-50 queries (find, update, insert) in 10 minutes for taking users informations. Also all the queries are async. Right now everything works fine. Just wondering if it will cause problems in the future. As you said if if you're in a position to say nothing exact, thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "does it cause trouble?"

Comment: Maybe connection timeout, query error etc.